# Matlab: Error using VideoFileReader/setup

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I'm using this code:

```
h = vision.VideoFileReader('num2.avi')

h = 
System: vision.VideoFileReader
Properties:
             Filename: '/Users/LoFe/Documents/BME/Work/Work/Work/num2.avi'
            PlayCount: Inf                                                
      ImageColorSpace: 'RGB'                                              
  VideoOutputDataType: 'single'
```

It is working well, but when I want to call step on it, i get this:

```
while ~isDone(h)
    hFrame = step(h);
end

Error using VideoFileReader/setup
Could not open the specified file.

Error in
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/matlab/system/+matlab/+system/+mixin   
/FiniteSource.p>FiniteSource.isDone
(line 39)
```

I'm using MATLAB 2013a, on OS X (Mavericks), what should I do? It is working fine on Windows 7.

Comment: My guess is that the codec that was used to encode the video is not supported on your Mac. For MATLAB, the supported codecs that the CVST video reader can read in are different between Mac and Windows.  Try using Handbrake to re-encode the file into a MP4 then try running the code again.  http://handbrake.fr/  Also, did you try using the `VideoReader` class? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the codec that was used to encode the video is may not supported on your Mac. For MATLAB, the supported codecs that the CVST video reader can read in are different between Mac and Windows.

As such, try re-encoding your video into a format that is native to the Mac, like a QuickTime movie file, or an MP4 file.  [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr) is a perfect tool to do this for you.

Also, perhaps try using MATLAB's native `VideoReader` class to see if you can read the file and extract video frames.  Take a look at its documentation for more details: http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader-class.html.

However, it looks like you have resolved the error, as converting it to a QuickTime movie file worked.

Glad I could help!

Comment: @Yvon - Nice workaround.  This doesn't require re-encoding, but you will need `avisynth` installed.  Minor setback though.

Comment: Just read this http://avisynth.nl/index.php/HOWTO:_AviSynth_video_processing_with_WINE I use avisynth a lot, and it's very easy to use, but I didn't realize they don't support Mac :( So one has to go through a long setup procedure to make it work - not a "minor" setback!