# Error using VideoReader/init (line 450)

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I tried this:
http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.html

after following this:
[Matlab: Error using VideoFileReader/setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286782/matlab-error-using-videofilereader-setup)

I am still getting the error:
"Error using VideoReader/init (line 450)
The file requires the following codec(s)
to be installed on your system:
    video/x-msmpeg

Error in VideoReader (line 147)
            obj.init(fileName);"

So, I did this:
sudo apt-get install libav-tools

but, I am still getting the same error

please help me in resolving either of the errors

Answer (score 1):

The MIME type `video/x-msmpeg` stands for **Microsoft** MPEG.  If you are running Linux, I highly doubt these codecs are installed on your computer out of the box.  However, you can try using the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package through `apt-get`.

In the terminal and assuming you are using Ubuntu, type in the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53 libavcodec53
sudo apt-get ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This should hopefully install what you need.  See here for more details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/214421/how-to-install-the-mpeg-4-aac-decoder-and-the-h-264-decoder

Comment: E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate

E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg' has no installation candidate

E: Package 'libavcodec-extra-53' has no installation candidate

E: Unable to locate package libavcodec53

this is the error am getting


I referred to the other link also that you posted. It's giving sort of same error

Comment: What about using just ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Comment: You'll have to reencode the video to something compatible. Sorry. Good luck. Serves you right to try and use Windows formats on Ubuntu.